# Laravel. Auth. FormRequest

Tags: laravel, laravel5, auth

Создал **FormRequest** под названием ValidationRegister, для того чтобы немного изменить стандартный контроллер регистрации. Так как увидел что большинство валидаций вынесены в **Request**.

Вот сама валидация:

```php
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'surname' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'gender' => ['nullable', 'string', 'max:10'],
            'birthday' => ['nullable', 'string'],
            'rules' => 'accepted',
        ];
    }
```

Суть вопроса состоит в том как правильно подключить и использовать его в контроллере регистрации

Стандартная валидация в контроллере

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }
```

Сам **request** был подключен к контроллеру

```php
use \App\Http\Requests\ValidationRegister as ValidData;
```

Пробовал различные варианты, ну ничего так и не получилась только выдаёт ошибку о том что передан один аргумент.

Comment: Приветствую. Проверьте, сколько данных приезжает в request от клиента. Можно тем же var_dump или чем нравится. Возможно какие-то данные реально не приезжают, а в rules стоит что они required

Comment: Добрый день! Проверял, точнее я использовал точно такую же валидацию в контроллере и оно всё работает

Comment: Наткнулся на [вот такой репозиторий](https://github.com/morilog/validator), возможно пригодится)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим У вас данные на регистрацию приходят в метод `register()`, тогда:

```
public function register (ValidationRegister $request) {
    //вывод и регистрация! <- если дойдет до данных строк, то валидация прошла успешно
}
```

`use App\Http\Request\ValidationRegister;` для подключения.

[Ссылка](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#creating-form-requests) на данный раздел

Comment: Вот в стандартной версии аутентификации есть такой метод protected function create(array $data)

Comment: @TigoVir лучше написать свою авторизацию, чем менять уже созданную. Как можно заметить анализируя контроллер там есть трайт `RegistersUsers`в котором и вызываются методы create и validator, в методе register() данного трейта. И в нем можно заменить свово Request на ValidationRegister но это правки в ядре и при обновлении фреймворка, данные затрутся!

Comment: А не подскажите где сам трайт находится?

Comment: @TigoVir и соответственно удалить $this->validator($request->all())->validate();   Для данной ситуации если принципиально оставить дефолтную авторизацию, просто добавьте ваш rules массив в метод validator() и всё. А formRequests используйте для других целей!

Comment: @TigoVir \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers.php

Comment: Мне вот прям принципиально сделать валидацию через FormRequest

Comment: А как мой класс то подключить в трайт?

Comment: так его возможно так подключить?

Comment: @TigoVir public function register(Request $request) такой метод в том трейте за место Request укажите свой созданный! Должно помочь. И удалите  $this->validator($request->all())->validate(); он уже не нужен будет (следующей строкой вызывается)

Comment: Он ругается на то что такой класс не найден

Comment: @TigoVir use App\Http\Request\ValidationRegister; в трейте! ошибся его надо подключить!

Comment: Оформите пожалуйста как ответ

Comment: Возникла проблема. Во время того как нажимаю регистрацию форма очищается ну ничего не происходит